# Unable to push my project to github repository via the CMD

Tags: git-push

According to my cousera tutor, I will be using git to host my website, So its basically Syncing my code to my git hub repository via CMD so anytime I'm making a change on my text editor, it will be effected on the git hub server. Anyway, the command for that via the CMD is git push after which it will request for authentication. Of course the authentication is always successful but I get an error message afterwards that the request was aborted and I couldn't create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: Could you please provide exactly what commands you are running and what errors are output? Just change any user identifiable information or secret information to some fake thing.

Comment: first i cd into my project folder then i run git status after which it will prompt me run git push

Comment: Could you please cut and paste in exactly the command you are running and then exactly the output?